# How do I separate these image picker function?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, uiimageview

I want to upload a third and maybe more images onto the image view but I don't know how to separate the third image. The first two works fine, how do I add the third function, i mostly need help on the func image picker controller i think.

```
var selected = 1


@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {


    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 1

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if selected == 1 {
            myImageView1.image = image
        } else {
            myImageView2.image = image
            return
        } 
       //i tried putting myImageView3 here but it just replaced the 2nd

    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {

       let image2 = UIImagePickerController()
    image2.delegate = self
    image2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image2.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 2

    self.present(image2, animated: true)
}


@IBAction func pickImage3(_ sender: Any) {
    let image3 = UIImagePickerController()
    image3.delegate = self
    image3.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image3.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 3

    self.present(image3, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add an unique tag for each image view. Avoid using 0 because the default tag is 0. So you will have image views with tags say 1 to 3. Set each image view like this

[image]

On your `viewDidLoad`, add a tap listener to all your image views. Call this method on all three image views one by one

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.tag = 1 
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then in image tap handler, record which image view is tapped by recording it's tag number. Since tag numbers are unique, we can use that to figure out which image view is tapped later

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    selected = tappedImage.tag
    self.present(image, animated: true)
}
```

Finally in image pick delegate, find your image view from it's parent view. Say you are adding your image views to self.view, simply get your view in this way and set image

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if let imageView = self.view.viewWithTag(selected) as? UIImageView {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @Riccardo Oh, you haven't defined it, right? Simply add this code to your view controller `var selected = 0`

Comment: @Riccardo Yup. When you click on the image, the `imageTapped` function will be triggered and your image picker view will appear.

Comment: it doesn't do anything when i click on it.

Comment: @Riccardo Are you sure you have already added the gesture recognizer on the image view? Is user interaction for that image view set to enabled? Hac you tried to put a break point in the handler function to see if it actually get called or not?

Comment: can I just use a button to select an image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148629/discussion-between-fangming-ning-and-riccardo).

Comment: need help again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978704/firebase-upload-images-and-getting-url-issue

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of repeated code. Create a single function for selecting a picture. Simply have each button action save off the appropriate image view that will be set once the picture is selected.

Here's the updated code:

```
var selectedImageView: UIImageView? = nil

@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedImageView = myImageView1

    selectPicture()
}

@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedImageView = myImageView2

    selectPicture()
}

@IBAction func pickImage3(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedImageView = myImageView3

    selectPicture()
}

func selectImage() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = false

    present(image, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if let imageView = selectedImageView {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }

    selectedImageView = nil

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can also use a single button action if you give each button a unique tag. Let's say you give the 3 buttons the tags 1, 2, and 3. Replace the 3 `pickImageX` methods with one:

```
@IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        selectedImageView = myImageView1
    case 2:
        selectedImageView = myImageView2
    case 3:
        selectedImageView = myImageView3
    default:
        break
    }

    if selectedImageView != nil {
        selectPicture()
    }
}
```

This assumes you are using a `UIButton` for this. Adjust as needed otherwise.